# Creating a menu strip with WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In .Net there is something called a menu strip. These are more customizable than HMENU's. How could I create one of these in unmanaged C++?

Thanks

Comment: While Microsoft clearly implemented native versions of the menustrip/statusstrip/toolstrip, I don't think they ever made it into the common controls library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't more customizable than HMENUs, they're just **easier** to customize. If you don't want to use [MFC C++ WinAPI wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0s49351(VS.80).aspx), what do you want to customize ?

Comment: Menu strips are dockable like toolbars, they can be placed in the same row as a toolbar, etc.  You'd have to completely rewrite the native Win32 menu to make it do that.

Comment: Not necessarily, based on that link from CodeProject (a must-have for MFC and useful for WinAPI, among others) : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/dockwnd.aspx

It's heavy, but possible : the menu would be hosted by a child window, to dock.

Also, I'm pretty sure MFC provides a way to do that easily.